# Calculating median for different subsets and sample sizes

Tags: missing-data, median

I have a basic question about calculating median.

The database I'm using contains registered records of criminals and the number of committed crimes per year each has committed in country X. Based on the database, there is a sample of 100 criminals that have committed at least one registered crime over the 3 years time.

Given that:

- Whole sample size is 100
- Year 1: 30 people that committed at least one crime
- Year 2: 50 people with at least one crime
- Year 3: 90 people with at least one crime

Now, I want to calculate a median number of crimes for each year in this sample, do I need to:

a) Find median with n= 30 in Y1, n= 50 in Y2, and n= 90 in Y3

-OR-

b) Assume that in Y1 30 criminals committed crimes and 70 committed 0 crimes and calculate median for this, then in Y2 assume 50 had 0 and median for all 100 and in Y3 10 had 0 crimes and median for 100 as well...

In other words, should I assume 0 in case the data is missing? 
It doesn't seem right to be 'adding' data points by saying there were 0 crimes. But on the other hand, shouldn't we treat our sample as correct for now and later highlight the assumptions?

Does it depend on the case? If so, how should I reason about it?